# Can I use 2 different User Journeys for the same Persona to show the flow of 2 different tasks that the user performs?

Tags: ux-field, personas, user-journey, scenarios

Can I use 2 different User Journeys for the same Persona to show the flow of 2 different tasks that the user performs?

My user has to perform 2 main tasks in the platform, and the tasks are a bit different in structures.

My user has 2 main goals to fulfill.

Comment: Yes, I would imagine you need to use the two journeys to show the two different tasks. I'm going to assume you're splitting it up by persona for a reason?

Comment: A user journey is aimed at capturing the end-to-end processes/steps involved in achieving a goal or accomplishing a task, so if you feel that there are two different goals or tasks and it is easier to document them separately then by all means do so. If you want to you can produce a summary of the two tasks and put them on the same diagram for a high level comparison as well.

Answer (score 3):

You user is functioning under two separate personas and each persona has a journey. When they switch persona, the journey switches as well. The challenge is designing the functionality. Ideally, each personas set of tasks can puzzle-piece with the other. Usually this is where a new design pattern will emerge.

Answer (score 2):

I treat personas as individuals who can have more than one task to accomplish on the site. Therefore, they can each have multiple user flows. I just completed a set of personas, each with 4-5 user flows. For example, one persona needs to register for the site, look up claim information, and dispute a claim. One person, one site visit, three tasks.

There might be a rule for personas saying they can only have one user flow, but I say do whatever supports your design process best.

Answer (score 1):

We recently did a high level journey that crosses multiple personas and then had "drill down " journey at the persona level. Those Journeys had even further drill down because the journey can reflect a switch in mental models.

Comment: Can you expand on this?